# How to change default interface for internet?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, routes

I have a PC with Ubuntu server 18.04 installed on it and I'm trying to use this PC as a server. There are 2 interfaces involved here:

1. To provide It's internet, I am using an android smartphone that has access to internet via it's Data and it will be sharing internet with my PC (server) via USB Tethering. This will create an interface called 'enp0s29f7u8'. This interface will get an IP automatically (DHCP?), mostly '192.168.42.249'.
2. There is another interface called 'enp2s0' which is a Huawei internet modem and it's connected to my PC with a LAN cable. This 'enp2s0' will serve as an Access-Point so I can SSH to my PC While I'm close. I installed 'ifupdown' on server so I can assign an Static IP to my Access-Point, namely '192.168.1.10'.

`$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.268.0.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1`

Here is the problem: I cannot access internet with this setups. It's like Ubuntu is trying to connect to Internet via 'enp2s0', which is only an AP with no access to internet.

So i tried
`sudo ifconfig enp2s0 down`
and there it is, i have internet. Also, when I do
`sudo ifconfig enp2s0 up`
after that, i still have access to internet.

How can I config my PC so that it will always use 'enp0s29f7u8' to access internet and use 'enp2s0' only as an AP?

p.s. 1: I really don't understand network stuff. I tried changing default gateway (I don't know why) but it didn't helped(at least the way i did).

p.s. 2: I'm not a native English speaker. Hope that I could talk my mind.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Your question does not belong on stackoverflow (questions about programming only https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) but on https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: @quant you are right. sorry about that and thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

To modify the routing table you have to use the command route.
If you run the command as super user it should show how the traffic is routed from your host. You have to change the default to enp0s29f7u8. In order to change it you can simply remove the default

`# route del default`

and add again

`# route add default dev enp0s29f7u8`

You can route only some address to the other interface. Have a look at the man for more option of the route command

Comment: Unfortunately, something went wrong with Ubuntu and it was broken really bad. I tried reinstalling the OS while both interfaces where connected and now it's working fine.

thanks for your time.